# WHERE subquery = 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query which checks if a question have any answers which are marked as a correct answer.

Now I tried using a subquery and I tried setting the subquery as a user-defined variable.

#### Test #1

```
SELECT
    @id := `id` AS `id`, `title`
FROM
    `eu_questions`
WHERE
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `eu_answers` WHERE `question_id` = @id AND `correct` = 1) AS UNSIGNED) = 0
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

#### Test #2

```
SELECT
    @id := `id` AS `id`,
    @count_correct := (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `eu_answers` WHERE `question_id` = @id AND `correct` = 1) AS `count_correct`
FROM
    `eu_questions`
WHERE
    CAST(@count_correct AS UNSIGNED) = 0
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

The queries doesn't result in errors, they simply return 0 results and I don't get why? I tried comparing the user-defined variable while selected and that seems to work and return the correct value, so that simply bugs me even more!

This is how I checked it:

```
SELECT
    @id := `id` AS `id`,
    @count_correct := (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `eu_answers` WHERE `question_id` = @id AND `correct` = 1) AS `count_correct`,
    CAST(@count_correct AS UNSIGNED) = 0
FROM
    `eu_questions`
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

#### Answer - Thanks to [Branko Dimitrijevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533120/branko-dimitrijevic)

I used his example and ended up with this query, which fits my needs.

```
SELECT *
FROM `eu_questions`
WHERE
    1 != ANY (
        SELECT COUNT(`id`)
        FROM `eu_answers`
        WHERE `question_id` = `eu_questions`.`id`
        AND `correct` = 1
    )
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: Anyone besides me refuse to use horizontal scroll bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM eu_questions
WHERE 1 = ANY (
  SELECT correct
  FROM eu_answers
  WHERE question_id = eu_questions.id
);
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce0ae/2)

Add extra WHERE and LIMIT conditions as desired...

Comment: Thanks, a modified version of this works! (I added it to the question itself)

Comment: @Vallentin Your query also returns questions that have zero correct answers. And doesn't those with exactly one correct answer. Why did you feel you need to use COUNT? On top of that, COUNT returns just one row, so ANY is unnecessary (you could have just used `0 <`).

Comment: because I want the query to return the questions which doesn't have any answers or have more than one answer.

Comment: @Vallentin OK, but then you should have worded your question differently from: _"I'm trying to write a query which checks if a question have any answers which are marked as a correct answer."_

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN on the answers table and use a where clause to keep only questions without correct answer.

```
SELECT
    `eu_questions`.`id`, `title`
FROM
    `eu_questions`
LEFT JOIN
    `eu_answers` ON `question_id` = `eu_questions`.`id` AND `correct` = 1
WHERE 
    `eu_questions`.`id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `eu_questions`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: That error occurs when both tables in the query have an id column. So, eu_questions and eu_answers both have an `id`. You need to specify which table's id is being referred to in the select and the order by and in the `ON`